# Why am I not showing up as contributor in github?

Tags: github, commit

Why my [github commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhWnH.png) are like this. Is this the reason that I am not showing up as a contributor.

Comment: Did you commit to feature branch, was it merged to master?

Comment: I committed to the master branch.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't appear in a repository's contributors graph, it may be because:

- You aren't one of the top 100 contributors.
- Your commits haven't been merged into the default branch.
- The email address you used to author the commits isn't connected to your account on GitHub.

[source](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/viewing-activity-and-data-for-your-repository/viewing-a-projects-contributors#troubleshooting-contributors)